# Triangular nav. bar

Tags: html, css, windows, web

I want to make a triangular navigation bar for my own website.
But when I tried to hover over some of the div's, some problems occured:
The background of the triangle image is still a square, so when I place both triangle images next to eachother and I hover over them, I can't select them individually.
So my question is how to make sure to ONLY hover over the image instead of the "background" div.

Made a small picture so you guys would understand what I mean: 
http://www.mupload.nl/img/fgvvsqzjoxl.png (my mouse is on the second image, and the hover effect is making the opacity lower)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code

Comment: Can this help you in some way? http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/
It's not triangular but can be easily adapted

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/eev3qu1e/1/)**

The trick is to apply border on hover as well (as we do when we create triangle by css)

html

```
<div class="tri-wrap">
    <div class="triangle up">
        <div class="tri-text-up">design</div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle down negativeM">
        <div class="tri-text-down">hand
            <br />made</div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle up last negativeM">
        <div class="tri-text-up txt-pad">illustration</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.tri-wrap {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 600px;
}
.triangle {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
.down {
    border-top: 120px solid #ee8172;
}
.up {
    border-bottom: 120px solid #11b9a6;
}
.down:hover {
    border-top: 120px solid #f2a698;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.down:hover:hover > .tri-text-down {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.up:hover {
    border-bottom: 120px solid #97c6c7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.up:hover:hover > .tri-text-up {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tri-text-down {
    margin: -6em -1.4em;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}
.tri-text-up {
    margin: 4.1em -1.75em;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}
.txt-pad {
    margin: 4.1em -3.1em;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}
.negativeM {
    margin-left: -5em;
}
.last {
    border-bottom: 120px solid #8393c9;
}
.last:hover {
    border-bottom: 120px solid #c0b1d6;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but the problem still remains, look at this image: http://www.mupload.nl/img/3k2e61xxyca.png

The red circle is the mouse, so when I'm still on the first triangle, the second one is already selected, and it shouldn't be that way.